# Activerecord has_one build new when association not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have this model relationships

```
class User
  has_one :wallet, :foreign_key => :user_id
end

class Wallet
  after_initialize :set_value

  def set_value
    # Whatever
  end
end
```

And I'd like that when I do `User.last.wallet`, `User.last.wallet.new` gets called.

I could achieve this by creating another method in the `User` model:

```
  def get_wallet
    self.wallet||self.wallet.new
  end
```

and call `get_wallet` when needed.

But can't I get this without this useless and dirty extra method?
Something like:

```
  has_one :wallet, :foreign_key => :user_id #, :build_if_not_found => true
```

Gems like this one: https://github.com/febuiles/auto_build don't do what I want: they build `Wallet` after creating the `User` object instead of creating when `User.last.wallet` is called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class User
  has_one :wallet, :foreign_key => :user_id

  def wallet
    super || build_wallet
  end
end
```

You still need to add some extra code, but it will do exactly what you want without any additional calls.